# Let $L,K\in \operatorname{End}_k(V)$ such that $L\circ K =0$. Is there an easy way to see that $\operatorname{Im}(L) \cap \operatorname{Im}(K)=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}\DeclareMathOperator{\I}{Im}$

> Let $L,K\in \End_k(V)$ such that $L\circ K =0=K\circ L$. Show that $\I(L) \cap \I(K)=0$.

Okay, this seems to be a rather trivial fact, as this is given without justificatin in my book as part of a proof of a theorem. And I can actually show it, but my proof of kind of long and not intuitive.

So my question is there an easy way to see this ?

I'm not sure if it is needed for this statement, but I also have that $L+K=I$, $L^2=L$ and $K^2=K$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true. Given any nontrivial vector space $V$ of dimension $2$ and any basis $(e_1, e_2)$ of $V$, define a transformation $T \in \text{End}(V)$ by $$T(e_1) := 0,\qquad T(e_2) := e_1.$$
Then, $T \circ T = 0$ but $\text{Im}(T) \cap \text{Im}(T) = \langle e_1 \rangle$.

Still, one can show the claim with your additional information, which just says that $K$ and $L$ are projections onto complementary subspaces of $V$, and if you have a picture in mind of what these operators looks like, then the claim may well be "obvious".

Anyway, one way to see this rigorously is as follows:

Since $K^2 = K$, $K$ fixes any element in the image of $K$, and likewise $L$ fixes any element in the image of $L$. So, let $v \in V$ be the image of both. Then,
$$v = Iv = (K + L)v = K v + Lv = v + v = 2v,$$
and so
$$v = 0.$$

**Remark** Note that your additional information actually implies that $\text{Im}(K) \cap \text{Im}(L) = \{0\}$: Composing both sides of $K + L = I$ with $K$ gives
$$K = K \circ I = K \circ (K + L) = K^2 + K \circ L = K + K \circ L$$
and thus
$$K \circ L = 0.$$
By symmetry,
$$L \circ K = 0.$$

Comment: I understand the first part, thanks for that :) But the second part, I don't understand. You end with that $LK=0=KL$, but that is already our assumption right ?

Comment: No, the first part shows that $KL = LK = 0$ is not sufficient to show that $\text{Im}(K) \cap \text{Im}(L) = \{0\}$, and then shows that (1) $K^2 = K$, (2) $L^2 = L$, and (3) $K + L = I$ *are* together sufficient to prove that the intersection is trivial. The remark shows that $KL = LK = 0$ is actually a consequence of (1), (2), and (3).

Comment: (And, you're welcome. :) )

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand also my confusion, because my book said. Blabla. Therefore $LK=0$ and hence $\I(L)\cap \I(K)=0.$ So I thought there was some magical connection.

Answer (score 0):

The result does not seem true. Consider, for instance, $K=L$ equal to an index $2$ nilpotent operator.